# Dashboard to aggregate Google Analytics, Facebook, YouTube etc tracking data?

Tags: google-analytics, facebook, youtube

I'd like to see as much tracking data as possible about my online presence, in one single dashboard - so views/conversions from Google Analytics data, the performance of my Facebook campaigns via the Insights API, views/clicks from my YouTube campaigns, etc.

This could be as simple as a graph with time on the x-axis, and key indicators from each source on the y-axis (conversions from Analytics, likes on Facebook, views on YouTube, etc).

The idea is that I can see customer engagement with each source, over time.

I can write my own such dashboard easily enough, but I wondered if there was something off-the-shelf that already did this.

Apologies if this isn't the right forum for such a question - would appreciate tips for the best place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Integrating Google Analytics and Youtube is pretty easy. Plus you can create custom dashboards in GA to display whatever information you want.

How to integrate Youtube with Google Analytics

http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=147619

This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878917/804087 on SO discusses ways to get facebook data into GA.

And this dashboard is very popular to show all social media in one dashboard in GA
http://www.customreportsharing.com/topic/40-social-media-dashboard/

[image]